# Google Maps api v3 not loading in Safari 8, IE11

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have the following code to load a Google map. It works in most browsers, but not in IE11 and Safari 8. Instead I just get the container background colour.

I think it has to do with the function not being called, because if I add an alert to the script, it also ignores that. That alert does work on the browsers where the map does load.

FYI - the php comes from a WP plugin Advanced Custom Fields.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCJ02VcPM0KRyiwWNd_hjr0nNnTMJkFmVs&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

    function init() {
        <?php
            $location = get_field("map_location", $contactpage);
        ?>

        var lat = <?php echo $location['lat']; ?>;
        var lng = <?php echo $location['lng']; ?>;
        var myLatLng = {lat, lng};

        var lat = lat + 0.016;
        var latLngCenter = {lat, lng};

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            zoomControl: false,
            scaleControl: true,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false,
            draggable: false,
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(latLngCenter),
            styles: <?php the_field("map_customization", $contactpage); ?>
        };

        var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);

        <?php
            if(get_field("show_map_marker", $contactpage) == 1) { ?>
                var mapicon = '<?php the_field("map_marker_image", $contactpage); ?>';
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: '<?php the_field('map_marker_title', $contactpage); ?>',
                    icon: mapicon,
                    optimized:true
                });

            //alert("show map");

            //Remap map on resize.
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");   
        <?php
            };
        ?>
    };

    $(window).resize(init);
    $(document).ready(init);
</script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue (I can't run your PHP...)

Comment: Sorry, will ensure for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get javascript errors in IE11: `SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'` on these lines:

```
var myLatLng = {lat, lng};
// ...
var latLngCenter = {lat, lng};
```

Those need to be:

```
var myLatLng = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
// ...
var latLngCenter = {lat: lat, lng: lng};
```

Comment: Fixed it in IE11. I assume it will fix it in Safari 8 (I have no way of actually testing this other than hearing back from someone who does still have Safari 8).